# BGS Groundhog software coordinate system input

Tags: coordinates, gis, 3d-modelling

Using BGS Groundhog professional software but it seems not to recognize D.D coordinates.
When input, the software seems to be assuming them as UTM.

Interchanged both X&Y (D.D) coordinates but loading at the same position.